# Maximize expected revenue for the store.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

On any given day the number of customers N arriving at the store has a Poisson distribution with mean value $\lambda \leq 100$. Each arriving customer, $i=1,2,...N$ spends $100-\left(\dfrac {\lambda} {100}\right) X_{i}$ dollars, where $X_{i}$ are *i.i.d* with continuous uniform distribution over $[0,100]$ dollars. $N$ and $X_{i}$ are assumed independent. Find the value of $\lambda$ which maximizes the expected revenue for the store and the maximum expected revenue.

About all I got here is that $E[NX] = E[N]E[X]$ and I'll probably have to take the derivative of something. Is this a case where a joint moment generating function would be helpful? I really could use a hand with this one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, but your notation with $X$ maybe confused you. Let $M$ denote the amount that each customer spends (not $X$). Then $$M=100-\frac{λ}{100}X$$ and $E[M]=100-\frac{λ}{100}E[X]=100-\frac{λ}{100}\cdot\frac{100+0}{2}=100-\frac{λ}{2}$. So

$$E[NM]=E[N]E[M]=λ\cdot\left(100-\frac{λ}2\right)=\frac{1}{2}λ(200-λ)$$ This is a quadratic in $λ$ and hence it is maximized at the midpoint between its roots (just take the derivative and go with the critical points to confirm this), so, at $$λ^*=\frac{0+200}{2}=100$$